# Passing string from page to another page is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to pass a string Id (example `ABCD`) to another page using `[routerLink]` however when it reaches the page I'm trying to send it to, it's undefined.

Here is how I am trying to pass the value.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items.Items">
<h3>
    <a [title]="item.Name" [routerLink]="['/page2', item.ItemID]">
        {{item.Name}}
        {{item.ItemID}} // This has a value
        {{item.Role}}
        {{item.CreatedOn}}
        {{item.IsActive}}
    </a>
</h3>
```

Here is the page component I am trying to send it to.

```
export class Page2Component implements OnInit {
ItemId: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
 }

ngOnInit(){
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
         this.ItemId = params.get('itemId')
    });
}
```

}

This is what the route path is:

```
{ path: 'page2/:itemId', component: Page2Component }
```

Can anyone see the issue here?

EDIT:

Here is how I am getting the `items`

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Item List';
  items: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

ngOnInit(){
    let resp      =this.http.get("https://localhost:8080/api/item/getallitems");
    resp.subscribe((data) => this.items = data);
  }
}
```

Comment: The implementation looks okay. You should check if `item.ItemID` really has some value.

Comment: @micronyks I print values from the `item` on the page I am sending from, including `item.ItemID` and it shows the values correctly.

Comment: @micronyks I've updated the question to show how I am printing the values on the sender page

Comment: It should still work. I'm trying in my local and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yeah. the implementation seems to be correct. Where are you trying to check the value of itemId?

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I've checked to see if the it has a value in the `ngOnInit` on the page I'm sending to but it's undefined

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I've added how I am getting the items

Comment: @micronyks I've added how I am getting the items. Could it be that the itemID is undefined in the for loop?

Comment: `<div *ngIf="items?.Items">` put this at top n see what happens

Comment: @JamesS I have set up StackBlitz with minimum code to reproduce your case - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gupfgy. Do you see there any difference between your solution?

Comment: @Buczkowski Thanks. The answer seemed to be that the code wasn't waiting for the subscribe to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that my code wasn't waiting for my subscribe to complete. So although it showed the data on the screen, the value in the loop was undefined at that point.

To solve this I created a function, added the subscribe call in there and called it from the `ngOnInit`. Below is the change I made.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getItems();
}

getItems(){
    let resp = this.http.get("https://localhost:8080/api/item/getallitems");
    resp.subscribe((data) => this.items = data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to subscribe to `queryParamMap` instead:

```js
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: By the looks of it, this sets `this.ItemId` to null instead of `undefined` now

Comment: There is a difference between `ActivatedRoute.queryParamMap` and `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` - https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params

Comment: Yes of course otherwise it would not exist. Why downvote me though? You can do it that way too. This answer is completely valid.

Comment: @Ploppy you just put info that OP could try to subscribe to `queryParamMap` yes he definitely can but what is the difference there? Why he can't achieve this by subscribing to `paramMap`?